# Unity project character only moving one way no matter where you touch on an IOS device

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine, 2d

this is the code for movement when touch on an IOS device in a 2D game i am creating in unity. but when i run it the game loads but when i touch to the right he moves to the left and when i touch to the left he also moves to the left.

i have used ScreenToWorldPoint as told to use but it dont seem to work he will only move one direction

```
 void PlayerWalkMobile()
{

    // force by which we will push the player
    float force = 0.0f;
    // the players velocity
    float velocity = Mathf.Abs(GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.x);

    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {

        countTouches++;

        Touch h = Input.touches[0];

        Vector2 position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector2(h.position.x, h.position.y));

        Debug.Log("the postion of the touch is " + h.position);



        if (position.x > 0)
        {

            // if the velocity of the player is less than the maxVelocity
            if (velocity < maxVelocity)
                force = speed;

            // turn the player to face right
            Vector3 scale = transform.localScale;
            scale.x = 1;
            transform.localScale = scale;

            // animate the walk
            animator.SetInteger("walk", 1);

        }
        else if (position.x < 0)
        {

            // if the velocity of the player is less than the maxVelocity
            if (velocity < maxVelocity)
                force = -speed;

            // turn the player to face right
            Vector3 scale = transform.localScale;
            scale.x = -1;
            transform.localScale = scale;

            // animate the walk
            animator.SetInteger("walk", 1);

        }
        // add force to rigid body to move the player
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(new Vector2(force, 0));

        // set the idle animation
        if (h.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
            animator.SetInteger("walk", 0);

    } // if Input.touchCount > 0

}
```

in the debug the touches are all over the place the 0.0 is the far left of the screen everywhere else is a minus 
the position of the touch is (-1093.7, 1048.3)

i thought

```
Vector2 position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector2(h.position.x, h.position.y));
```

was supposed to make 0.0 the centre

Comment: Does setting `scale.x = -1` reverse the direction? If so, you are also reversing the direction by setting `force = -speed`.

Comment: scale.x = -1 reverse the direction is correct it turns the guy to face the other way